# Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC (MPI, Intel compiler, wrappers)

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, mpi, intel

I am compiling MPI-based C++ code with PrgEnv-intel/5.2.82.
I am using cmake/3.0.2 and cray-mpich/7.0.4.
My commands are:

```
    export CC=mpiicc
    export CXX=mpiicpc
    cmake ./path_to_my_CMakeLists.txt
    make
```

But I am having this error:

```
    CMake Error at /.../cmake-3.0/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:57 (message):
      Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

      mpiicc.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:11 (project)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be something you need to ask your local sysadmin. Most likely, the documentation for your system will show you exactly what you need here.

Comment: are you sure `mpiicc` and `mpiicpc` are the right wrappers ? these are the good ones if you are using Intel MPI and compilers, but i am not sure of this with cray mpich. btw, what does `which mpiicc` says ?

Comment: `mpiicc` and `mpiicpc` are the names of the compiler wrappers in Intel MPI. For generic MPICH those are usually `mpicc` and `mpic++` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with that I was using an old version of cmake, so it didn't work with the Intel compilers. When I changed to cmake/3.7.1, everything worked perfectly.